# Agrupar datos y realizar cuenta

Tags: r

Parto de los siguientes datos:

```
library(tidyverse)   

structure(list(CURSO = c("1º de E.S.O.", "1º de E.S.O.", "1º de E.S.O.", 
     "1º de E.S.O.", "1º de E.S.O.", "1º de E.S.O.", "1º de E.S.O.", 
     "1º de E.S.O.", "1º de E.S.O.", "1º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", 
     "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", 
     "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", 
     "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", 
     "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", 
     "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", "3º de E.S.O.", 
     "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", 
     "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", 
     "2º de E.S.O.", "2º de E.S.O.", "3º de E.S.O.", "3º de E.S.O.", 
     "3º de E.S.O.", "3º de E.S.O.", "3º de E.S.O.", "3º de E.S.O.", 
     "3º de E.S.O.", "3º de E.S.O.", "3º de E.S.O.", "3º de E.S.O.", 
     "3º de E.S.O.", "3º de E.S.O.", "3º de E.S.O.", "3º de E.S.O.", 
     "3º de E.S.O.", "3º de E.S.O.", "3º de E.S.O.", "3º de E.S.O.", 
     "3º de E.S.O.", "3º de E.S.O.", "4º de E.S.O.", "4º de E.S.O.", 
     "4º de E.S.O.", "4º de E.S.O."), Col1 = c("Bien", "Bien", "Bien", 
     "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", 
     "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", 
     "Mal", "Mal", "Bien", "Mal", "Mal", "Mal", "Mal", "Mal", "Mal", 
     "Mal", "Mal", "Mal", "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", 
     "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Mal", "Mal", "Mal", "Mal", "Bien", "Mal", 
     "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Bien", "Mal", 
     "Mal", "Bien", "Bien", "Mal", "Mal", "Mal", "Mal", "Bien", "Mal", 
     "Mal", "Mal", "Mal"), SEXO = c("M", "H", "H", "M", "H", "H", 
      "H", "H", "H", "M", "H", "H", "M", "M", "H", "M", "H", "M", "H", 
      "M", "M", "M", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "M", "H", "M", "M", "M", 
      "M", "H", "H", "M", "M", "H", "H", "H", "H", "M", "M", "M", "H", 
      "H", "H", "M", "H", "M", "M", "H", "M", "M", "M", "H", "M", "M", 
      "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "H", "H")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
     "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -65L)) -> datos
```

Los agrupo por curso y sexo:

```
datos %>%
  count(CURSO, SEXO, Col1) %>%
  group_by(CURSO,SEXO)
```

y obtengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrupando por curso y sexo quiero hacer la cuenta Bien / (Bien + Mal)

Por ejemplo, para 2º de E.S.O. y hombre
9/(8+9) *100 =52,94

Quedando algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo fácilmente mediante `pivot_wider()` para que `Bien` y `Mal` los tengamos en una sola columna y de esta forma el calculo sale directo:

```
datos %>%
  count(CURSO, SEXO, Col1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=Col1, values_from=n, values_fill=0) %>% 
  mutate(tasa = Bien/(Mal + Bien)*100)

# A tibble: 8 x 5
  CURSO        SEXO   Bien   Mal  tasa
  <chr>        <chr> <int> <int> <dbl>
1 1º de E.S.O. H         7     0 100  
2 1º de E.S.O. M         3     0 100  
3 2º de E.S.O. H         9     8  52.9
4 2º de E.S.O. M         9     4  69.2
5 3º de E.S.O. H         5     1  83.3
6 3º de E.S.O. M         6     9  40  
7 4º de E.S.O. H         0     2   0  
8 4º de E.S.O. M         0     2   0
```

No es la salida exacta que buscas, pero creo que es la forma apropiada de mostrar los datos, sin embargo, tampoco es complicado armar una salida más parecida a lo que muestras en tu pregunta:

```
datos %>%
  count(CURSO, SEXO, Col1) %>%
  left_join(
    datos %>%
      count(CURSO, SEXO, Col1) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from=Col1, values_from=n, values_fill=0) %>% 
      mutate(tasa = Bien/(Mal + Bien)*100,
             Col1 = if_else(Bien > 0, "Bien", "Mal")),
    by = c("CURSO", "SEXO", "Col1")
  ) %>% 
  select(-c(Bien, Mal))
```